# How to map java.time.Instant to Nodatime.Instant when creating a Xamarin Android Native binding

Tags: android, xamarin.android, nodatime, java.time.instant, xamarin-binding

I'm creating a Xamarin Native binding for an Android library, and one of the issues I notice is that types from `java.time` (specifically `java.time.Instant` type) does not get mapped. I assume because of this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/8081.

`Xamarin.Android` does have the NodaTime NuGet package available which provides similar functionality as `java.time` in Android. I'm curious to know if there is a way to make it so that when creating a binding, it can use NodaTime in places where `java.time` would be used instead.

Is there a way to do this? Can I create a binding library for `java.time`? or have some way to automatically use NodaTime where Java.time types are needed?